# Can one force jump into engaged?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-force-and-destiny

If one moves normally it is so that you move into short distance then another maneuver to move into engaged.

But my question is now if I use force jump (enhance force tree) and am able to jump medium distance and the distance between me and the enemy is short to start with. Can I jump into engaged already by using force jump only once?

Answer (score 1):

### The Short Answer

To move to a specific location within Short Range of an opponent using Force Leap from Medium Range will require the *Force Enhance Power*, the *Horizontal* or *Vertical Leap* Control Upgrade (depending on context), and the *Range* Upgrade. It can benefit from the *Maneuver* Control Upgrade. The cost for this leap will be 1 Force Point for the use of the power, and 1 for the Range Upgrade.

Once in Short Range, the character will still need to use *1 Maneuver* to Engage their target. They may not simply use Force Leap to Engage the target.

They will be able to Leap from Medium Range to Engaged in one Turn for the cost of 1 Action (Force Leap) and 1 Maneuver (Engage). To also attack in that same turn, they will need to complete their progress in the Control Upgrades associated with Force Leap in the Enhance Force Power tree so that they can perform Force Leap as a Maneuver instead of as an Action.

**How to do it:**

As explained in **Chapter 6: Conflict and Combat**, in a normal combat, the character will have 1 Maneuver and 1 Action available. For the cost of Strain (or other explicitly stated means), they may take a second Maneuver.

Under the **Move Maneuver** in the *Maneuvers* section of Chapter 6 of the three core books, it states the cost for Engaging or Disengaging an opponent. It specifies directly that this is a cost independent of being in Short Range, and identifies that the use of this Maneuver is intended to represent getting into or out of a position where physical attacks are possible.

There are many ways to close range with an opponent. The use of Force Leap is an awesome one that can not only be cool in the mind's eye, but can serve tactical benefits as well, such as voiding obstacles, cover, and rough terrain, or crossing empty expanses or towering levels of Star Warsian architecture.

If a character has Force Leap, what can they expect to accomplish? They can either close to Engaged and Not Attack, or close to Engaged and Attack depending on their proficiency with the Force Power and the number of Maneuvers they have available in addition to their Action:

**Leap Only**

A character with the Force Leap Control Upgrade can use 1 Action to leap to any location in Short Range that can be accessed physically by a leap, such as clearing cover. This manifests first as horizontal distance (with enough elevation to clear obstacles), and then in its second Control Upgrade can be vertical distance as well.

What they can accomplish with the Leap in terms of changing proximity to a target or their location is limited to inside the Short Range Band. In all other respects, it will be the same as the next entry, *Leap + Range Upgrades Only*.

**Leap + Range Upgrades only**

Without the 'Maneuver' Control Upgrade for Enhance's 'Force Leap' Control Upgrade, a character will be able to close to Short Range with their 1 Action. They will be not be Engaged unless they pay the Maneuver to become so. As their Action has been used they will be unable to attack this turn. This allows leaping from Disengaged and at Medium Range, into Engaged.

- If they are acting before the target character and are concerned about being attacked, they may adopt a Guarded Stance for the cost of their 1 Maneuver.
- If they are acting after the target character they will have 1 Maneuver left to use for something else, such as 'Preparing' a weapon, drawing one, and so on. No attack is possible.

**Leap + Range + Maneuver Upgrades**

If they have the 'Maneuver' Control Upgrade, they may Leap into Engaged for the cost of 1 Maneuver to Leap and 1 additional Maneuver to become Engaged with the target. They have not used their Action yet, so they may then also launch an Attack Action, all within the same turn. This allows leaping from 'Disengaged and at Medium Range' to 'Engaged and able to Attack.'

---

### The Full Explanation

The original question, in essence, asks how many Force Leaps (Force Enhance power) are required to move into Engaged with a target from the Medium Range Band. This question can be confusing as Engaged functions as much as a Condition as it does a Range. This is certainly the sort of thing a good Star Wars RPG group will want to enjoy, but to preserve the ability of all characters to act in tune with the source material, the basic assumptions of the combat system need to be kept in mind.

### How is it a Range Band?

It can best be defined as a special range category within the Short Range Band that allows for Brawl, Melee, and Lightsaber attacks (which are themselves a subcategory of Melee), and offers potential complications or adjustments to Ranged attacks. Entering Engaged has a cost in Maneuvers.

### How is it a Condition?

In order to interact with an object (pick it up, etc), in order to punch someone, or in order to land an attack with a hand-held weapon like a knife or vibro-ax, the character must be 'Engaged' with the target of their chosen action. To achieve the condition of 'Engaged' a player must spend one Maneuver to make that happen. This is the cost of attaining the condition, and is levied *in addition to* the movement required to get into Short Range.

**On Maneuvers**

There are numerous ways to gain one additional Maneuver listed in the core rules, such as exchanging one's Action for one, taking Strain for one additional Maneuver, or getting one as a bonus due to rolled Advantages, or Threats (as the GM's provision of an out-of-turn Maneuver). There are also rare Talents that can allow a third Maneuver. Unless affected by a specific Talent or other power description that clearly lifts the restriction, *no more than two Maneuvers may be taken* in a turn by a character. This is clearly stated in the Maneuvers section of *Chapter 6*, under the **Maneuver Limitations** heading.

> Note on the out-of-turn Maneuver
>
> This ruling allows a character to gain a Maneuver (if it makes sense
>   to the group in context) during the action of an opponent, as the
>   interpretation of Threats or Despair. This does not occur during the
>   character's turn, and cannot be stacked with their normal Maneuvers.
>   If a character were to close to Short, but lack the Maneuvers to
>   Engage, or found the opponent then used their turn to Disengage, IF
>   that opponent then suffered a tragic roll, the character could be
>   awarded with a bonus Maneuver to use at that moment. They could use it
>   to close to Engaged, or to Engage again, before their turn came around
>   again.

**Force Leap**

This power is found in **Age of Rebellion** and **Force and Destiny** in the *Force Powers* section of *Chapter 8: The Force*. It requires an Action until the character has earned the final Control upgrade in the Enhance Power tree. The Force Leap power appears as one of the many Control upgrades in this tree. Its first iteration offers horizontal leaps. This can be improved to include vertical distance with another upgrade. The final Control upgrade in this branch of the tree allows the leap to be a Maneuver, not an Action.

Also on this branch of the Enhance Force power is the sole Range upgrade in the tree, and it allows the leap to be extended into the Medium Range Band (any location from Short to Medium, or Medium to Short, not blocked from access to physical movement). As the text for the Range upgrade specifically bans it, the Range upgrade may not be invoked multiple times to Leap farther than this.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have my EotE or FaD books handy, but in the AoR book,  on page 299 it says:

> **Range Upgrade**: Spend Force pip to increase the maximum range the Force user can jump by the number of Range upgrades purchased...

That in no way says you have to use your full range when jumping, it just increases how far you can go.  Jumping a shorter distance is even easier, unless you think there's some challenge that should require a roll (ie: jumping to be engaged with a character on a small pillar in a giant arena with a Nexu growling below.. ).

Furthermore on AoR page 215, a move action can let you change range increment, engage or disengage from an opponent, or move with in short range. Unless you think moving next to the target is made more difficult by the terrain or available space it shouldn't even require a jump let alone a Force jump to close the distance. That being said if your character wants to add flair by making it a Force jump let him, cause that makes it more cinematic.

If the character is moving from Medium to engaged, I wouldn't require 2 move actions to do so. Mechanically this is supported on AoR page 221 when it says "Consider engaged a subcategory of short range".

Comment: Although with normal movement if I start at medium range I need to spend 1 maneuver to enter short range and another maneuver to enter engaged "distance".  Or when I'm already at short range I need to spend 1 maneuver to enter engaged "distance". Would a medium rnage force jump reduce that to 1 maneuver each?

Comment: My last sentence addressed that. Moving from either Medium or Short to engaged should only be one movement, because engaged is a subcategory of short range. You're just saying in the entire area covered by short range you're putting yourself in arms reach with the target rather than just out of his reach.

Comment: Looks like a few people in the FFG forums disagree with my interpretation: [https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/187850-engaged-range-questions/?hl=%2Bmedium+%2Bengaged#entry1784917]

Comment: Tnx. read it. hmmm Lets see if we can get them to clarify it.

Comment: Made a post there for clarification maybe one of the posters of the thread you mentioned will answer there. Else your answer here is quite good. lets wait for a day what comes up in that thread for clarifications about their interpretation there.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like rules as written the answer is no, this post does a nice job of describing engagement:[Engagement as a subcategory of short range](https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/187850-engaged-range-questions/#entry1785061)

And this one points out the issues with defining "engaged" as a subcategory of short: [Treat engaged as its own range band](https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/187850-engaged-range-questions/#entry1851895)

*To avoid confusion in the comments I'm adding this as a new answer rather than editing my original one.*

Comment: The above being said, if the user is using the Enhance power to perform a force jump, they're spending an Action to make the movement (unless they have the Control upgrade to make it a Maneuver) when they would just be able to perform 2 maneuvers (even an additional Maneuver granted by extra advantage), and just wouldn't be able to attack in the same round. AND it sounds COOL! _Hardly something I'd discourage at the table unless a player is constantly abusing it._

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's OK to link to other resources in your answers, but we ask that you put a summary of the linked resource into your answer, just in case the link ever breaks. You can use the "edit" button at the bottom of your answer to add more information to it.

Comment: @Leo If this answer is correct, could you substantiate why it's the case, and as Oblivious Sage mentioned, **include the key concepts from your links** that substantiate this answer? Pretend those links were going to 404 next week - what does your answer need to say to still make sense? (Forum links _do_ break from time to time as topics get moved or as sites change their URL scheme, and Stack Exchange aims for its questions and answers to be useful for years to come still.)

Comment: I've placed a downvote on both answers for now, as having two answers, one apparently incorrect, the other correct but not clearly substantiated, is a poor situation to be in. When one of those is clearly substantiated and shown correct (like this one!) that'll become an upvote instead for that answer. I've additionally put a bounty on the question which is up for grabs for this answer or others depending on their quality.